# parse.com. take names by filters objective c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

[image]

I have 3 strings for Filters and need to receive a name of a lens by using this filters.

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"lences"];
    [query whereKey:@"brand" equalTo:_brandString];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
```

I make a code for 1 filter "brand" and need to add another 2 (type and aperture) to receive a names of lances

Comment: Do you mean objects that match brand AND type AND aperture? Or brand OR type OR aperture?  Do the former (conjunction) with additional `whereKey:` statements on the same query.  Do the disjunction with three queries and Query.or();

Comment: yes to match all filters.  I have such code :                                           PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"lences"];
    [query whereKey:@"brand" equalTo:_brandString];
    [query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:_typeString];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
    }];
}                          where I need to write additional WhereKey @"type"

Comment: Yes. Add another and they will act as AND conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To form a conjunction of conditions, apply them to a single query...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"lences"];
[query whereKey:@"brand" equalTo:_brandString];
[query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:_typeString];
[query whereKey:@"aperture" equalTo:_apertureString];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
}];
```

Only objects matching all three conditions will be returned.